# Ambiguous getter for Field... Room persistence library

Tags: android, android-room

I have the following Entity

```
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    private final long id;

    private String _id;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
}
```

However when I try to create table for this entity in android using room persistence library, I get the following error.

`Error:(18, 20) error: Ambiguous getter for Field(element=_id, name=_id, type=java.lang.String, affinity=TEXT, columnName=_id, parent=null, indexed=false). All of the following match: getId, get_id. You can @Ignore the ones that you don't want to match.`

The `_id` field is included so that I can directly translate the responses from the `node.js`api hooked up to a `mongodb` database.

Comment: If your class listing is complete, then I suspect that Room does not like fields with the same base name, differing only in the `_` prefix. Can you do something on the JSON side, like `@SerializedName` with Gson, to allow the field to have a different name (e.g., `mongodb_id`)? Also, is your class listing complete, or are there getter methods that your current listing does not show?

Comment: you mean when I get the response from the API? will it automatically serialize all the _id fields to mongodb_id?

Comment: Yes, I am asking if that is a possibility. I do not know what you are using for your Web service client API. Some JSON parsers that work on Android, such as Gson, support annotations like `@SerializedName`, so that the name in the JSON can be different than the Java field name.

Comment: Use `@SerialName("_id") String "yourval" ;` this will help you for sure.

Answer (score 13):

You need to have setter and getter for each private field else you should make them public, another reason that may cause this error is having two getters or setters for a field.

Comment: Helped  a lot. I was having 2 getters with different names for same field.

Answer (score 6):

For Room :

In my case

```
public String getpBSalesTotal() {
    return pBSalesTotal;
}

public void setpBSalesTotal(String pBSalesTotal) {
    this.pBSalesTotal = pBSalesTotal;
}
```

is the previous POJO class that i want as a table in my database.

> I have just changed small "" p "" to capital ""P"" and that solved my
>   error

. Like below

```
public String getPBSalesTotal() {
    return pBSalesTotal;
}

public void setPBSalesTotal(String pBSalesTotal) {
    this.pBSalesTotal = pBSalesTotal;
}
```

to generate this type of

> POJO form JSON

you can use this [LINK](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). It worked for Room.

Answer (score 2):

> As per documentation you need to declare getter for every field.

I can see that you have not declared your class with @Entity annotation.
Also make sure you are using latest version of library as it is still in development you need to expat some ground breaking changes.

See below example it is working fine for me with below api version of Room.

```
api 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha8'
```

Or you can use "alpha9" as well.
Hope this will solve your problem.

```
@Entity (tableName = "user")
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String _id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@NonNull
private String passwrod;

public User(String userName, @NonNull String passwrod) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.passwrod = passwrod;
}

@Ignore
public User() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPasswrod() {
    return passwrod;
}

public void setPasswrod(String passwrod) {
    this.passwrod = passwrod;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Me also face the same issue. While I remove the

> "_"  underscore symbol, from "_id"

then works fine.

```
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    private final long id;

    private String myid;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
}
```

It works for me and I hope it work for others. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Return types for getters should be the same as the attribute data type, if you have attribute of data type int, When I found out it fixed my problem.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If this happens again, I would highly suggest you to autogenerate the getter and/or the setter with the help from Android Studio.

This way you won't risk using time on this issue again.

To see how, please check this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684109/11208147)