# error : Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor and Cannot find setter for field

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am new in android architecture component. I am trying to build app with the reference of [android-architecture-components/BasicRxJavaSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample) with the same **Gradle** configuration. But I get the following errors..

- Error:(14, 8) error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:= Department(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) : [id : null, dep : null]
- Error:(16, 20) error: Cannot find setter for field.
- Error:(18, 20)error: Cannot find setter for field.

I am using Version "1.0.0-alpha9" for all architecture Components. I have tried with current "1.0.0-beta1" version also.

I have looked [Ambiguous getter for Field… Room persistence library
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660379/ambiguous-getter-for-field-room-persistence-library) link also but according to google sample not need to setter for every field.

Model class

```
    @Entity(tableName = "tblDepartment")
public class Department{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String mId;

    private String mName;

    @Ignore
    public Department(String dep) {
        mId= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        mName= dep;
    }
    public Department(String id, String dep) {
        mId = id;
        mName=dep;
    }

    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is with an `Expense` class. Your question shows a `Department` class. Either you have the wrong error message or the wrong code.

Comment: I mistakenly added wrong error log.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your getters/setters don't match your field names so currently you have:

`private String mId;`

`public String getId() {}`

The Room preprocessor is looking through your class and failing to find a getter/setter for your `mId` field because it is expecting `public String getMId()` Same with your constructor, the parameter names are not matching the field names so it can not find a valid constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid constructor trough the names.

And getters/setters for all fields you are storing trough Room.

Try:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tblDepartment")
public class Department{
@PrimaryKey
private String mId;

private String mName;

@Ignore
public Department(String mName) {
    mId= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.mName= mName;
}
public Department(String id, String name) {
    this.mId = mId;
    this.mName=mName;
}

public String getId() {
    return mId;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}
public void setId(String mId){ this.mId = mId; }
public void setName(String mName){ this.mName = mName; }
}
```

Comment: [check this google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/User.java) . Here no public constructor is used.

Comment: The problem is that you dont use the Column name and your POJO doesnt have the same name of your variables in the getters

Comment: Thanks @Marcos for your help, I tried but its not working

Comment: Hi @Marcos my code uploaded [here on git](https://github.com/biswanathgit/Andorid-Room-Rx/tree/origin/SetUpCode) if you check, it will very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:-

```
@Ignore
public Department(int mId, String mName) {
   this.mId= mId;
   this.mName= mName;
}

public Department(String mName) {
   this.mName= mName;
}
```