# error: Cannot find getter for field in Android Room

Tags: java, android

This is a simple a class in android studio:

```
package com.loghty.bahaa.loghty;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;


@Entity (tableName = "Chars")
public class Chars {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "char_Id")
    private int pCId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "char_field")
    private String mcharField;

    // Getters and setters

    public String getMcharField() {
        return mcharField;
    }

    public void setMcharField(@NonNull String mcharField) {
        this.mcharField = mcharField;
    }

    public int getpCId() {
        return pCId;
    }
}
```

But when I build the app I get this error in the pCId field:

> error: Cannot find getter for field

I checked the code many times but nothing is strange. where is the error exactly ?

Comment: It may be a capitalization issue. Usually a getter is of the form `getCamelCase()`, so the first letter after the `get` portion is in uppercase. Try renaming your method to `getPCId()`, with a capital P, and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you consider renaming?did that work?

Comment: After I renamed the fields, setter and getters with CamelCase style the erorr is gone...thank you guys.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks its work for me as well, it was the issue with getCamelCase().

Comment: I got that error either because my getter was @NonNull, or because my field was private. Private means even Room can't get to it, so it must be public, so Room doesn't think it must use the getter, which doesn't work for a converted field.

Answer (score 5):

Change the variable from private to protected or public

from `private int pCId;`

to 
`protected int pCId;`

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

1. add the constructor with and without the *auto generated id*
2. add the @Ignore annotation to the constructor without the *auto generated id*
3. add the getter with camelCase
4. clean all the data before the first install on device because i don't want to do the [migration](https://medium.com/google-developers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929).

   ```
   @Entity(tableName = "words")
   public class Word {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   private int id;

   @NonNull
   @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
   private String mWord;

   public Word(int id, @NonNull String mWord) {
       this.id = id;
       this.mWord = mWord;
   }

   @Ignore
   public Word(@NonNull String mWord) {
       this.mWord = mWord;
   }

   public int getId() { return id; }

   public String getWord(){ return this.mWord; }
   }
   ```

Comment: > add the getter with camelCase < was the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when the getter fun return type was different from the field's type (`DateTime` vs `String`):

```
val timestamp: String = DateTime.now().toString()

fun getTimestamp(): DateTime = DateTime.parse(timestamp)
```

Room was skipping a generation of `getTimestamp()` fun for the `timestamp` field because Room was thinking it's already created. Wheres, the type mismatch caused an exception because types are not matching.

The **solution was to rename the getter fun**:

```
val timestamp: String = DateTime.now().toString()

fun getTime(): DateTime = DateTime.parse(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Room and the variable is a boolean, then remember that the getter is named isVariableName() and not getVariableName().

I would highly suggest that - if the error should come again - then use Android Studio to autogenerate your getter and setter. That way you won't run into this issue again.

To do so:

1. create your variable
2. right click the variable
3. press "Alt + Insert" or press "Generate".
4. Choose what you want autogenerated:

[image: screenshot of how to autogenerate getter and/or setter]